# cannot remove Object::Version in dependencies.rb:629 rails 2.3.12, ruby-1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dependencies, ruby-on-rails-2

So, it's hard for me. Trying to run locally rails-2.3.12 app on ruby-1.8.7 (ugh).
But when running `ruby script/server` getting error like this:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:629:in `remove_const': cannot remove Object::Version (NameError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:629:in `remove_constant'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:629:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:629:in `remove_constant'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:575:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:575:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:575:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.12/lib/commands/server.rb:84
    from script/server:3:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

I don't really want to hack rails to add dependencies, but ready for everything to get this old thing running. Can you help with this?

Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (2.3.12)
      actionpack (= 2.3.12)
    actionpack (2.3.12)
      activesupport (= 2.3.12)
      rack (~> 1.1.0)
    activemerchant (1.17.0)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.11)
      braintree (>= 2.0.0)
      builder (>= 2.0.0)
      json (>= 1.5.1)
    activerecord (2.3.12)
      activesupport (= 2.3.12)
    activeresource (2.3.12)
      activesupport (= 2.3.12)
    activesupport (2.3.12)
    airbrake (3.0.4)
      activesupport
      builder
    andand (1.3.1)
    babosa (0.3.8)
    barcoder (1.0.0)
    bluecloth (2.2.0)
    braintree (2.12.0)
      builder (>= 2.0.0)
    builder (3.0.0)
    cancan (1.6.7)
    chunky_png (1.2.5)
    cocaine (0.4.0)
    columnize (0.3.4)
    compass (0.11.5)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      fssm (>= 0.2.7)
      sass (~> 3.1)
    compass-susy-plugin (0.9)
      compass (>= 0.11.1)
    daemons (1.0.10)
    dalli (1.0.5)
    escape (0.0.4)
    fastercsv (1.4.0)
    friendly_id (3.2.1.1)
      babosa (~> 0.3.0)
    fssm (0.2.7)
    httpclient (2.2.1)
    iconv (0.1)
    json (1.6.1)
    kgio (2.6.0)
    linecache (0.46)
      rbx-require-relative (> 0.0.4)
    meta-tags (1.2.6)
      actionpack
    mime-types (1.16)
    money (2.0.0)
    nokogiri (1.5.0)
    paperclip (2.8.0)
      activerecord (>= 2.3.0)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.2)
      cocaine (>= 0.0.2)
      mime-types
    postgres (0.7.9.2008.01.28)
    pr_geohash (1.0.0)
    rack (1.1.2)
    rails (2.3.12)
      actionmailer (= 2.3.12)
      actionpack (= 2.3.12)
      activerecord (= 2.3.12)
      activeresource (= 2.3.12)
      activesupport (= 2.3.12)
      rake (>= 0.8.3)
    rake (0.9.2)
    rbarcode (0.0.2)
      rmagick (>= 1.15.9)
    rbx-require-relative (0.0.5)
    rdoc (3.10)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rmagick (2.13.2)
    rsolr (0.12.1)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
    rspec (1.3.2)
    rspec-rails (1.3.4)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rspec (~> 1.3.1)
    ruby-debug (0.10.4)
      columnize (>= 0.1)
      ruby-debug-base (~> 0.10.4.0)
    ruby-debug-base (0.10.4)
      linecache (>= 0.3)
    sass (3.1.4)
    sequel (3.20.0)
    sinatra (1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    soap4r (1.5.8)
      httpclient (>= 2.1.1)
    sqlite3 (1.3.4)
    sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
      sqlite3 (>= 1.3.3)
    sunspot (1.2.1)
      escape (= 0.0.4)
      pr_geohash (~> 1.0)
      rsolr (= 0.12.1)
    sunspot_rails (1.2.1)
      nokogiri
      sunspot (= 1.2.1)
    taps (0.3.23)
      rack (>= 1.0.1)
      rest-client (>= 1.4.0, < 1.7.0)
      sequel (~> 3.20.0)
      sinatra (~> 1.0.0)
      sqlite3-ruby (~> 1.2)
    will_paginate (2.3.15)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activemerchant (= 1.17.0)
  airbrake
  andand
  barcoder (= 1.0.0)
  bluecloth
  cancan
  compass (= 0.11.5)
  compass-susy-plugin (= 0.9)
  daemons (= 1.0.10)
  dalli (~> 1.0.4)
  fastercsv (= 1.4.0)
  friendly_id (~> 3.2.1)
  iconv (= 0.1)
  json
  kgio
  meta-tags (~> 1.2.6)
  money (= 2.0.0)
  paperclip (~> 2.7)
  postgres
  rails (= 2.3.12)
  rbarcode
  rdoc
  rspec-rails (~> 1.3)
  ruby-debug
  sass (= 3.1.4)
  soap4r (= 1.5.8)
  sunspot_rails (~> 1.2.1)
  taps
  will_paginate (= 2.3.15)
```

Comment: Was this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444649/rails-2-3-5-startup-remove-const-cannot-remove-objectnotsupported-nameerror

Comment: Try removing half your gems (and associated initializers) at a time until there are none left but rails.

Comment: that old answer hasn't really helped me to avoid this issue, but thanks for the guess
Yo mean remove everything, and leave just rails gem?

Comment: Yes, try removing half your gems (and associated initializers) at a time until there are none left but rails.

Comment: You seem to have picked up the 'right' version of the gems, but maybe you should still try to put `bundle exec` in front of your command?

Comment: no difference with `bundle exec` :(